# Execute file specific tests on Git,Gerrit,Jenkins workflow

Tags: git, jenkins, gerrit

**SCM - Git, 
CI - Jenkins**

I have **configured the Git,Gerrit & Jenkins workflow** and configured Automation suite on a jenkins slave.

I am able to **run the TestNG suite on the slave machine** after a patch set is created on Gerrit.

But currently **for any kind of patchset created on Gerrit the same test suite is invoked**. What I want to achieve is **perform tests based on the file name which was pushed into Gerrit**.

eg. If **login.jsp** is pushed then **login tests** should be performed not the full test suite.

Any tips on how this can be achieved? The direction in which I am currently thinking is, **Is there any way to notify the slave about the name of the pushed file?**

Comment: Curious; why would you want this? Isn't the purpose of jenkins to build the entire project so you know it still works even with your new changes?

Comment: I think you would have to call a script that parses out the Changelog.xml for the path, and then have that call your new build with `http://server/job/myjobname/buildWithParameters?PARM1=Value1&PARM2=Value2` ... Sounds like a lot of work

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Execute Test Scripts on slave based on the filename committed on SCM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22478388/how-to-execute-test-scripts-on-slave-based-on-the-filename-committed-on-scm)

Comment: Yes this is a duplicate question. I had to ask it again as it was nt addressed earlier. (Wld love to knw an alternative way of re-posting a question). Now coming to the curiosity, the whole test suite might run for 3-4 hours, Case- I don't want to run the full suite after minor changes on a login page.

Comment: @Cole9350 - It would be really helpful if you can elaborate little more on the suggestion you stated. I hope my intention is clear... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use Git to find the files modified by the commit being tested (or the files modified compared to the tip of the branch, whatever is most appropriate). For example,

```
git diff-tree -r --name-only HEAD~1 HEAD
```

lists the paths of the files modified in the currently checked out commit.